# Calculate the determinant of matrix by recurrence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

My homework is to calculate the determinant:
$$
\det(A) =
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_1 & a_1 & \cdots & a_1 \\\ a_1 & a_2 & a_2 & \cdots & a_2 \\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\ a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_n \end{vmatrix} = V(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$$
and following is my proof.

Expand $A$ using the first line:

$$
\det(A) = (-1)^{1+1} a_1 \begin{vmatrix} a_2 & a_2 & \cdots & a_2 \\\ a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_3 \\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\ a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_n \end{vmatrix} + (-1)^{1+2} a_1 \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_2 \\\ a_1 & a_3 & \cdots & a_3 \\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\ a_1 & a_3 & \cdots & a_n \end{vmatrix} + (-1)^{1+3} a_1 \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_2 \\\ a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_3 \\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\ a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \end{vmatrix} + \dots + (-1)^{1+n} a_1 \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_2 \\\ a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_3 \\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\ a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_{n-1} \end{vmatrix} 
$$

Or
$$
\det(A) = a_1 \det(A_{1,1}) - a_1 \det(A_{1,2}) + \sum\limits_{i=3}^{n} a_1 (-1)^{1+i} \det(A_{1,i})
$$

If $i \geq 3$, the first two columns of $A_{1,i}$ are proportional, then $\det(A_{1,i})=0$. Moreover
$$
\det(A_{1,1}) = V(a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)
$$
and
$$
\det(A_{1,2}) = \frac{a_1}{a_2} V(a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}
V(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) & = a_1 V(a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n) - a_1 \frac{a_1}{a_2} V(a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n) \\\ & = a_1 \frac{a_2 - a_1}{a_2} V(a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n) \\\ & = a_1 \frac{a_2 - a_1}{a_2} a_2 \frac{a_3 - a_2}{a_3} V(a_3,\dots,a_n)
\end{align}
$$
Since $V(a_n) = a_n$,
$$
V(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) = a_1 \frac{a_2 - a_1}{a_2} a_2 \frac{a_3 - a_2}{a_3} \dots a_{n-1} \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{a_n} a_{n} = a_{1} \prod_{i=2}^{n} (a_i - a_{i-1})
$$

For the feedback, I've got a simple remark "wrong" by the grader, but I still cannot find where the error is.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since you are dividing by $a_2$, $a_3$, ..., $a_n$, you should tell what happens if one of them is $0$ (I did not check all the details, but at first glance your method seems to work though).

Comment: Subtract the first column from all the others to reduce it to a determinant of size $(n-1)\times (n-1)$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thanks, I think this is an error.

Comment: You have two lines with formulas for $\det(A_{1,1})$ in terms of $V(\dots)$, the second one should be adjusted, the sub-index is $(1,2)$.

Comment: Thanks, this is my spelling error.

Comment: Take a look at the last pages of Darij Grinberg's [work](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.09777)